# Getting error in using photobucket api using C#.

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, photobucket

I have copied the C# code from Photobucket api and i am editing as per my need but i am not able to fix the following problem:

[image]

Can anyone suggest me how to overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply, timestampClient does not exist (or is inaccessible) at each point where you see the underlined variable with that message.

If it needs instantiating then set whatever like:

`TimestampClient timestampClient = new TimestampClient()`

For this to work you need to ensure that you declare timestampClient somewhere accessible by your `DisplayMessage` method

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar issue mentioned [here](http://photobucket.com/developer/forum?read,3,1671) by one of the guy and he resolved it by downloading the source code from [here](https://github.com/dextrin21/Photobucket.NET)